# Read reports Bad File Descriptor despite getc successfully using the same fd to read a char

Tags: c, errno, getc

I have this C code:

```
FILE * fd = fopen(filename,"rb");
printf("%c ",(char)getc(fd)); // returns expected char
unsigned char buffer[10];
printf("%d ",read(fd, &buffer, 10)); // -1
printf("%d\n",errno); // 9
```

`getc` returns a char from the input file, as expected. However `read` returns an error (-1) and `errno` is set to 9 (bad file descriptor). Clearly the file descriptor is OK, since `getc` manages to use it to read a char.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler yell out a warning at you? Take warnings serious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen` and `read` are functions of different families. The families are:

- `fopen` with `fread` (and also `getc`), from the C standard library.
- `open` with `read`, from the POSIX specification.

The first family uses file pointers as `FILE*` types, while the second one uses file descriptors as `int` types. You can't mix the two families as long as you don't convert from one file descriptor type to the other. The conversion from `FILE*` to `int` is done with the POSIX function `fileno`.

In your case, use `fread` to read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `read(fd, &buffer, 10)`
You want to use: `fread(buffer, 1, 10, fd)`
a `FILE*` is not a file-descriptor, it is a stream; that's why you have to use `fread()` (which needs a stream) instead of `read()` (which needs a file-descriptor). Also, `buffer` should be used instead of `&buffer` (which would lead to UB).

Answer (score 0):

It's weird code. You want to print the return code of read, not the data that was read?

First fix your read, you need fread instead of read:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *" stream );
```

The crash is caused because you overwrite the **address** of buffer, you don't write into the buffer itself.

So `printf("%d ",read(fd, &buffer, 10));` should be `printf("%d ",fread(buffer, 1, 10, fd));` instead, to read 10 (`nmemb=10`) bytes (`size=1`) into the buffer.

Comment: a FILE*, returned by fopen() is not a file descriptor; read() needs a file-descriptor; fread() should be used here instead. – shrike just now   edit